# Can Illusory Creature make ranged attacks?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

If you create the image of a creature with a ranged attack, such as a creature armed with a Longbow or a creature with [launch-able spikes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=294), can [*illusory creature*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=158) use those for their attacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Illusory Creature* cares about when the creature makes a [Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=89) and Strikes can be ranged attacks.

The Illusory Creature can make a ranged attack provided that

- the target still thinks that the *Illusory Creature* is real,
- the target reasonably believes they are being attacked,
- the target is within 500 feet from you.

In the case of the Manticore's Spike Volley attack it would still only deal 1d4 plus your spellcasting ability modifier. Even if multiple imaginary/illusory spikes hit.

Comment: "Phantasmal Force", one of the archetypcial spells creating illusory creatures that can fight originated in literature with the John Carter stories, from which Gygax drew the inspiration for the spell. (Originally *Phantasmal Forces*). In the story, the illusionists create phantasms of archers. This of course has no direct bearing on the rules interpretation here, but I found it interesting when I learned about it.